# How to connect my QToolButton to setIndexPage on my QStackedWidget in Qt?

Tags: qt, user-interface

I have a `QStackedWidget` whose first page is set to `Wgt1`. `Wgt1` contains 3 buttons `btn1,btn2` and

> btn3

. I want to do following

1. When widget starts it should setIndex as zero that is my first page on `QStackedWidget`.
2. When I press `btn1,btn2` and `btn3` , I should move to indexPage 1 , 2 and 3 respectively.

I wanted to use signal and slot so tried to connect the `clicked()` signal of `QToolButton` to s`etCurrentIndex(int)` slot of `QStackedWidget`. But It does not work as `click()` does not send any (int) value required by `setCurrentIndex(int)`. So for this I thought to override the `MousePressEvent(MouseEvent *e)`. I want to do something like to introduce a new `signal(int)` in my `Wgt1` so that it will emit some certain integer value on pressing the buttons on first page.

But to implement this I am not clear about following

1. Which `MousePressEvent()` I should override? For my `Wgt1`(which contains the buttons) or for the `QToolButtons` which is contained by my `Wgt1`?
2. If I want to override for `Wgt1` how I can detect which `QToolButton` is pressed in the `QMousePressEvent`?

   1. If I want to override for `QToolButton` how to write it? Should I create a new class deriving from QToolButton? or can I assign some function pointer or event handler to `MousePressEvent()`?

If you can answer the above questions it will be helpful otherwise you can suggest any other way also to solve this problem.
I don't know if I explained my problem clearly or not. Please revert back I will try to explain it more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many possible solutions, but I recommend to use [QSignalMapper](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qsignalmapper.html).  I think that overriding an event handler is more complex than necessary.

The code would look something like:

```
QSignalMapper* sm = new QSignalMapper(this);

// connect to `clicked' on all buttons
connect(btn1, SIGNAL(clicked()), sm, SLOT(map()));
connect(btn2, SIGNAL(clicked()), sm, SLOT(map()));
connect(btn3, SIGNAL(clicked()), sm, SLOT(map()));

// setMapping on each button to the QStackedWidget index we'd like to switch to
// note: this affects the value passed via QSignalMapper::mapped(int) signal
sm->setMapping(btn1, 1);
sm->setMapping(btn2, 2);
sm->setMapping(btn3, 3);

// finally, connect the mapper to the stacked widget
connect(sm, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), stackedWidget, SLOT(setCurrentIndex(int)));
```